# Python multithread http server

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple multithreaded http server which answers requests after 5 sec.
This code does not work, two simultaneous requests take 10 sec to complete, and I don't understand why.

```
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class ThreadingSimpleServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    pass

import sys
import os
import time     

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("answer")
        return

server = ThreadingSimpleServer(('', 8000), Handler)

try:
    while 1:
        sys.stdout.flush()
        server.handle_request()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Finished")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `handle_request`, which handles one request after the other. You have to use `serve_forever`, so that the server can handle request automatically.

Comment: Just changing handle_request by serve_forever does not seem to make it work either, am I missing something else ?

Comment: As I said in the question, when I use 2 tabs in chrome to connect to the server, they are answered in order, and it takes 5*2 seconds

Comment: How do you measure the time? For me, it takes exactly 5 seconds for each request.

Comment: For me too it takes exactly 5 seconds for each request, but if I open two chrome tabs, and quickly hit refresh on those 2 tabs, I see that it takes roughly 10 seconds to complete. Plus I can see when the first tab answers, after roughly 5 sec, while the second keeps spinning for an extra 5 sec

Comment: Seems to me, you have a problem with your browser not with your server code.

Comment: yeah indeed, it seems to work with firefox. Any idea what could cause this ? Do you reproduce it too ?

Comment: Your Browser might use the same connection for multiple requests.